# Prevent automatic form reset on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/" method="get">
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I can do the following:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But then the form doesn't actually get submitted... Any help?

Comment: then use ajax .... search for `jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.get()` methods

Comment: There is no way other than use AJAX request.

Comment: Yes. Submitting the form actually tells the browser to go to that path specified in the `action` attribute. The easiest way to do it is with Ajax.

Comment: if you're trying to save the state of the form this could help https://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbformstate It uses LocalStorage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp